# tkinter: how to replace a button with a image?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a tic-tac-toe game where a 3x3 grid, or matrix contains clickable buttons. when a button object is pressed, I want the button replaced with a image of an X or an O. this is what I have so far. Any help would be great.

```
from tkinter import *

def setX(canvas) :
    x = PhotoImage(file = 'E:\X.png')
    #what to do here to replace button on grid with X or O image?


def create_grid(event=None):
    w = c.winfo_width() # Get current width of canvas
    h = c.winfo_height() # Get current height of canvas
    c.delete('grid_line') # Will only remove the grid_line

    # Creates all vertical lines at intevals of 100
    for i in range(0, w, 200):
        c.create_line([(i, 0), (i, h)], tag='grid_line')

    # Creates all horizontal lines at intevals of 100
    for i in range(0, h, 200):
        c.create_line([(0, i), (w, i)], tag='grid_line')

root = Tk()     
c = Canvas(root, height=600, width=600, bg='white')
c.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

c.bind('<Configure>', create_grid)

b = []
for _ in range(9):
    b.append(Button(c, text="Click", width=10))

b[0].place(x = 60, y = 70)
b[1].place(x = 265, y = 70)
b[2].place(x = 455, y = 70)
b[3].place(x = 60, y = 275)
b[4].place(x = 265, y = 275)
b[5].place(x = 455, y = 275)
b[6].place(x = 60, y = 475)
b[7].place(x = 265, y = 475)
b[8].place(x = 455, y = 475)


root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For starters, `SetX` needs to be aware of the button it should replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getting the buttons to have an image can be kind of tricky (you kind of need a 2 layered approach), but changing the image is easy.

```
x_image = 'x.png'
o_image = 'o.png'
```

then...

```
x_image_for_button = PhotoImage(file=x_image)
o_image_for_button = PhotoImage(file=o_image)
```

then.....

```
button = tk.Button(self.controller, image=o_image_for_button, command=lambda: command_or_something)
button.config(width="40", height="40")
button.place(x=5, y=5)
```

(add in self. or root. etc)

now all you do to change the image is:

```
button.set(image=o_image_for_button)
#on second thought... maybe use button.config(image=o_image_for_button) insted
```

easy :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the button number to the setX function so it knows what button was clicked.  Also, you also should have a check to see if button was already clicked.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

def setX(button_num) :
    ##x = PhotoImage(file = 'E:\X.png')

    ## if button hasn't been clicked before, change the
    ## color and text, and add to list of buttons clicked
    if button_num not in clicked_buttons:
        b[button_num].config(text="X or O")
        b[button_num].config(bg="red")
        clicked_buttons.append(button_num)
    else:
        print("Already clicked")

def create_grid(event=None):
    w = c.winfo_width() # Get current width of canvas
    h = c.winfo_height() # Get current height of canvas
    c.delete('grid_line') # Will only remove the grid_line

    # Creates all vertical lines at intevals of 100
    for i in range(0, w, 200):
        c.create_line([(i, 0), (i, h)], tag='grid_line')

    # Creates all horizontal lines at intevals of 100
    for i in range(0, h, 200):
        c.create_line([(0, i), (w, i)], tag='grid_line')

root = Tk()     
c = Canvas(root, height=600, width=600, bg='white')
c.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

c.bind('<Configure>', create_grid)

b = []
place_positions=[60, 265, 455, 60, 265, 455, 60 ,265, 455]
for _ in range(9):

    ## add a command= to call the setX function and
    ## pass this button number to it using partial
    b.append(Button(c, text="Click", width=10,
             command=partial(setX, _)))
    this_y=475
    if _ < 6:
        this_y=275
    if _ < 3:
        this_y=70
    b[_].place(x=place_positions[_], y=this_y)

"""
b[0].place(x = 60, y = 70)
b[1].place(x = 265, y = 70)
b[2].place(x = 455, y = 70)
b[3].place(x = 60, y = 275)
b[4].place(x = 265, y = 275)
b[5].place(x = 455, y = 275)
b[6].place(x = 60, y = 475)
b[7].place(x = 265, y = 475)
b[8].place(x = 455, y = 475)
"""
clicked_buttons=[]

root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.mainloop()
```